# Why am I not getting the correct result from Object.entries in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a function getKey(index) that gets the key of an array of data at a specific index. However, this first needs to be filtered, using a function called byAuthor. However, when I try to use this in conjunction with getKey, it doesn't work as I expect. This is probably some sort of logic error, but I'm not really sure how to get the desired result.

```
getKey = (index) => {
    offersRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      if (data) {
        let fullData = _.filter(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
          return byAuthor(value, firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        }))
        this.setState({ fullData })
      }
      console.log('the key is' + Object.keys(this.state.fullData)[index])
    })
  }
```

This function should log the key of the object, as shown in the image below.
[image]However, it logs 0. Apparently this.state.fullData = 0, 1, 2, 3. The deadline for this project is very soon, so it would be great if anyone could help me. Thanks!

Edit: I have tested it again, and if I add `console.log(Object.keys(data))` it prints the keys that I am looking for. But once I run it with fullData, the keys turn into 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

FullData is an array, so `Object.keys(this.state.fullData)[index]` will always return index. What do you expect to get?

Comment: I wanted it to get the key of the offer at that index, which should be "-M9gvgkSK_wlYvHjmj7l" for example. I'm not exactly familiar with Javascript or Firebase so please correct me if I'm wrong, but ```Object.keys(this.state.fullData)``` should be an array of these keys instead of just 0, 1, 2, 3. The data structure of the array is such that each index is similar to the one shown in the image above, so I'm not sure where the 0, 1, 2, 3 comes from.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now - the keys of the array refer to the index of each object. How do I get it to return the key of the object from Firebase instead?

Comment: @MeganYap this.state.fullData[index] i guess, you dont need keys, you need values

Comment: but if I use ```this.state.fullData[index]``` or ```Object.values(this.state.fullData)[index]``` it just returns the object without the key, so just author: ..., category: ... etc

Comment: If you take a look at my edit I have done some more testing and it shows that when I assign fullData to the filtered version of data it replaces the keys with 0, 1, 2, 3